# Excel: Using "SMALL" Function Inside Array Formula

Tags: excel

I'm working in a spreadsheet developed by a colleague of mine and am doing some testing of the array formulas that currently exist.  My question is pretty short and to the point, see formula below:

```
={SMALL(INDEX('Wellfield Data'!$C$2:$C$10000, MATCH(ROW('Wellfield Data'!$C$2:$C$10000), ROW('Wellfield Data'!$C$2:$C$10000))), ROWS($A$1:A1))}
```

For some reason, this is evaluating as "#NUM"; see attached screenshot.

[image]

For reference, also attached is a screenshot of the data in the "Wellfield Data" tab:

[image: Wellfield Data]

Why is my original formula in cell V3 of the first screenshot not evaluating to "Zink Flare Inlet"?

Comment: `SMALL` doesn't return text (?).

Comment: But if you look at my formula, by row 9, it should be returning "8".  That isn't working either.

Comment: Any ideas as to why it isn't working at row 9?

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually trying to do... maybe explain that first?

Answer (score 0):

Remember, everything is either Number, Label or Formula!  Function Small in Excel finds a Number, the Nth smallest in the array.  To find a specific Label in a sorted list of Labels, you need something different, like Min for the first in a sorted list.  To find other positions than max and min in the (sorted) list of the array, you might think you need to sort the array.  However, with a helper column, you can do more: https://www.pryor.com/blog/excel-sort-formulas-how-to-sort-dynamic-data/